# Snapd service not running / problem installing snap packages on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, snap

Having some trouble with snap for installing Heroku. Never used it before, usually use pip. Here's what happens:

```
(legal_subs_3.6) (xenial)amessios@localhost:~$ sudo snap install heroku --classic
error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/heroku: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory


(legal_subs_3.6) (xenial)amessios@localhost:~$ snap find heroku
error: cannot list snaps: cannot communicate with server: Get http://localhost/v2/find?q=heroku&scope=wide: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory
```

I've been through the fixes/checks I can find so far online to no avail:

```
(legal_subs_3.6) (xenial)amessios@localhost:~$ snap --version
snap    2.39.2ubuntu0.2
snapd   unavailable
series  -


(legal_subs_3.6) (xenial)amessios@localhost:~$ sudo service snapd start
snapd: unrecognized service


(legal_subs_3.6) (xenial)amessios@localhost:~$ sudo service snap start
snap: unrecognized service


(legal_subs_3.6) (xenial)amessios@localhost:~$ systemctl status snapd
Failed to get properties: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1


(legal_subs_3.6) (xenial)amessios@localhost:~/code/test_projects/lawyer_bios/lawyer_bios$ systemctl start snapd.service
Failed to add /run/systemd/ask-password to directory watch: No such file or directory
Failed to start snapd.service: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1
See system logs and 'systemctl status snapd.service' for details.


(legal_subs_3.6) (xenial)amessios@localhost:~/code/test_projects/lawyer_bios/lawyer_bios$ systemctl status snapd.service
    Failed to get properties: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Just restart the service.

```
$ systemctl start snapd.service
```

Comment: Perhaps with 'restart' instead of start.

Answer (score 4):

If you are on Windows WSL run these these commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/DamionGans/ubuntu-wsl2-systemd-script.git
cd ubuntu-wsl2-systemd-script/
sudo bash ubuntu-wsl2-systemd-script.sh
# Enter your password and wait until the script has finished
cmd.exe /C setx WSLENV BASH_ENV/u
cmd.exe /C setx BASH_ENV /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Check the issues with systemd and snap in WSL here:
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/2374

https://github.com/damionGans/ubuntu-wsl2-systemd-script

Comment: ::::::::::::WSL users: Works like a charm!!! thanks for sharing

Answer (score 3):

if you faced this problem then open terminal and just type

```
sudo service snapd start
```

Comment: Please explain how this answer differs from that by 
Parveen Singh!

Answer (score 3):

```
systemctl start snapd.service
```

is used when you use Ubuntu or other system with "systemd" init system.
If you use system with sysvinit (like MX Linux, for example) you should use:

```
sudo service snapd start
```

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting snapd.apparmor if the other services did not help

```
sudo systemctl restart snapd.apparmor
```