# `snap list` hangs (missing /run/snapd.socket): should I report?

Tags: snap, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Ubuntu running under WSL2. This works fine for the most part, but `snap list` is hanging with no error. I ran `strace snap list` and saw this:

```
/run/snapd.socket"}, 20) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(7, "\0", 1)                       = 1
futex(0x55c51b93cec8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL) = 0
...
```

Seems the daemon is not running? I am wondering if this is bug report worthy, or if WSL2 does some weird stuff that makes it inapplicable?

**System**

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

**Other output from `strace`:**

```
read(8, "initrd=\\initrd.img WSL_ROOT_INIT"..., 512) = 162
read(8, "", 350)                        = 0
epoll_ctl(4, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, 8, 0xc0004ffa5c) = 0
close(8)                                = 0
readlinkat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/exe", "/usr/bin/snap", 128) = 13
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/snap/snapd/current/usr/bin/snap", 0xc000194858, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/snap/core/current/usr/bin/snap", 0xc000194928, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/snap/bin/snap", 0xc0001949f8, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/lib/snapd/maintenance.json", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/lib/snapd/maintenance.json", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
futex(0xc000034d48, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
getuid()                                = 1000
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 8
connect(8, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(8)                                = 0
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 8
connect(8, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(8)                                = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/nsswitch.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=510, ...}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 8
newfstatat(8, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=510, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
read(8, "# /etc/nsswitch.conf\n#\n# Example"..., 4096) = 510
read(8, "", 4096)                       = 0
newfstatat(8, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=510, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
close(8)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 8
newfstatat(8, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1501, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
lseek(8, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
read(8, "root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash\n"..., 4096) = 1501
close(8)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/carlerik/.snap/auth.json", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
futex(0xc000100148, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x5557cf729ec8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL) = 0
futex(0x5557cf729a80, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x5557cf729ec8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL) = 0
futex(0xc000100148, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x5557cf729a80, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x5557cf729ec8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

Comment: The last answer relating to WSL2 actually fixed my issue, so yes.
https://askubuntu.com/a/1251175/165026